How to use prompt-toolkit key binding with inner prompt
I have a prompt_toolkit application where I want a bunch of keys to be acted on immediately, without pressing Enter. It's not a fullscreen app, it's just using the bottom_toolbar. So I have set up key bindings:
class Annotator:
    def process(self):
        kb = KeyBindings()

        @kb.add("5")
        def _(event):
            self.buildJohnnyFive()

        @kb.add("s")
        def _(event):
            self.needInput()

        text = prompt("> ", bottom_toolbar=self.bottomToolbar, key_bindings=kb)
        print(f"You said: {text}")

    def buildJohnnyFive(self):
        self.buildHim() # Do work

    def needInput(self):
        raw = prompt("input> ", bottom_toolbar=self.bottomToolbar)
        self.useInput(raw)

    def bottomToolbar(self):
        return f"Current: {self.status1} - {self.status2}"

This works well, and the functions get called. However, in some of these functions I need to accept more specific input from the user. But when I call prompt() from inside the function bound to a key, I get an exception:
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/Users/nick/my_app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/application/application.py", line 714, in read_from_input_in_context
    context.copy().run(read_from_input)
  File "/Users/nick/my_app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/application/application.py", line 694, in read_from_input
    self.key_processor.process_keys()
  File "/Users/nick/my_app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/key_binding/key_processor.py", line 273, in process_keys
    self._process_coroutine.send(key_press)
  File "/Users/nick/my_app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/key_binding/key_processor.py", line 188, in _process
    self._call_handler(matches[-1], key_sequence=buffer[:])
  File "/Users/nick/my_app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/key_binding/key_processor.py", line 323, in _call_handler
    handler.call(event)
  File "/Users/nick/my_app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/key_binding/key_bindings.py", line 127, in call
    result = self.handler(event)
  File "/Users/nick/my_app/src/annotator.py", line 110, in _
    self.addCustomED()
  File "/Users/nick/my_app/src/annotator.py", line 145, in needInput
    raw = prompt("input> ", bottom_toolbar=self.bottom_toolbar)
  File "/Users/nick/my_app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts/prompt.py", line 1425, in prompt
    return session.prompt(
  File "/Users/nick/my_app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts/prompt.py", line 1035, in prompt
    return self.app.run(
  File "/Users/nick/my_app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/application/application.py", line 1002, in run
    return asyncio.run(coro)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 33, in run
    raise RuntimeError(

Exception asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

I understand the problem: I'm already running a prompt(), which hasn't ended yet, and now I'm asking for another, inner prompt which conflicts with the existing event loop.
What I don't understand is: how am I supposed to do this? I need to call the initial prompt so that the user gets the info in the bottom toolbar. There needs to be a run loop so that the app doesn't quit before the user has time to press keys. But then how am I supposed to get input at this inner function? Can I somehow end or suspend the outer prompt while the inner prompt is waiting for the user's input? I don't want to switch to doing everything on the one prompt, because then the user will have to press Return every time. And I actually don't WANT the terminal to fill up with lines of input commands.
Some guidance would be much appreciated.

maybe you should use normal input()?

maybe you should check source code for prompt() - maybe it can get existing loop as parameter. OR maybe it runs loop and later it runs some other function which you could run and skip second loop.

I don't have this problem when I use simple example with two prompt - maybe better create minimal reproducible example which we could simply copy and run.

I couldn't test it but in source code for prompt() I found information about option in_thread
(you can find it also in documentation for prompt())
in_thread: Run the prompt in a background thread; block the current thread. 
           This avoids interference with an event loop in the current thread. 

So maybe it will work
prompt(">", in_thread=True, ...)


This works! Great work looking through the code. It's a little wonky, because it draws the secondary prompt at the cursor, but somehow really believes that it's at column 0. So there's some character overwriting. But it does work. The Right Way™ for something this complicated, I have learned, is to use an Application with widgets. Unfortunately, I haven't gotten that working quite yet.
